# Find probability of addition of random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables

> Suppose you toss a coin four times. The sample space Ω = {HHHH,HHHT,HHTH,...,TTTT} contains 16 outcomes and you should assume
>   each outcome is equally likely. Let X be the Binomial random variable
>   that corresponds to the number of heads in an outcome, e.g., X(HTHT) =
>   2. Let Y be the Bernoulli random variable that evaluates to 1 if there is an even number of heads in the outcome, e.g., Y (HHHT) = 0 and Y
>   (HTHT) = 1.
>
> Let Z = X +Y, e.g., Z(HTHT) = X(HTHT)+Y(HTHT) = 2+1 = 3. What are the
>   values of:
>
> P(Z=0) P(Z=1)...P(Z=5)

Lets talk about Z=0.

In order for Z=0 to be true, X=0 and Y=0. So then, to get P(Z=0), do I have to find the intersection of X=0 and Y=0 or do I add P(X=0) and P(Y=0)?

Comment: Intersection.  your variables are not independent, so care must be taken.  If $X=0$ then of course $Y=1$, so $P(Z=0)=P(X=0\cap Y=0)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X = 0$ then $Y = 1$, and $Z = 1$

If $X = 1$ then $Y = 0$, and $Z = 1$

If $X = 2$ then $Y = 1$, and $Z = 3$

If $X = 3$ then $Y = 0$, and $Z = 3$

If $X = 4$ then $Y = 1$, and $Z = 5$

Therefore,

$P(Z=1) = 5/16$

$P(Z=3) = 10/16$

$P(Z=5) = 1/16$

$P(Z=0) = P(Z=2) = P(Z=4) = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Remember $Y= \begin{cases} 0 &:& X\in \{1,3\} \\ 1 &:& X\in\{0,2,4\}\end{cases}$ so

$$Z=\begin{cases}1 &:& X\in\{0,1\}\\3 &:& X\in\{2,3\}\\ 5 &:& X\in\{4\}\end{cases}$$